# Writing custom auth + how can I check to which endpoint request is going

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd want to implement my own authentication layer but I'm not sure

a) whether this approach is OK - is it similarly safe to jwt (except validating issuers and so on)?

b) how to decide whether endpoint that's being requested has an e.g `[CustomAuthorize]` attribute which indicates that you gotta be authorized in order to get into that endpoint?

I have to use e.g reflection to get path for `HomeController` `TestMethod`?

---

Sample pseudo code:

Read token from `__MyToken` http header and then check whether is does exist in Dictionary

If it doesn't then redirect to `/login/`

otherwise add `UserInfo` to `HttpContext.Items`

Of course, later I'd want to move _loggedUsers to some other service that would be injected here via AuthMiddleware's constructor, but now I'm just trying to get the concept

```
public class AuthMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictonary<Guid, UserLoginInfo> _loggedUsers = new ConcurrentDictonary<Guid, UserLoginInfo>();

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        Guid? token = context.Request.Headers.First(x => x.Key == "__MyToken")?.Value;

        if (EndpointWithAuthorizeAttribute(context.Request.Path) && TokenIsInvalid(token))
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/login/"); 
        }
        else
        {
            // in order to access that data in controller, later.
            context.Request.HttpContext.Items.Add("UserData", _loggedUsers[token]);
            await next(context);
        }
    }

    private bool TokenIsInvalid(Guid token)
    {            
        return
        token == null ||
        token == Guid.Empty || 
        !_loggedUsers.ContainsKey(token) || 
        DateTime.Now > _loggedUsers[token].ExpirationTime);
    }
}

public class UserLoginInfo
{
    pubic Guid Id { get; set; }

    pubic DateTime ExpirationTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: “I'd want to implement my own authentication layer but I'm not sure” – But why? Usually, when someone wants to do the rather insane thing of implementing their own authentication stack, then they should be proficient enough with the framework to figure out themselves on how to integrate it into the framework. – If you need a separate authentication mechanism, then you should look into creating your own authentication scheme on top of the existing authentication framework. I will personally not give out any guidance on going around that though.

Comment: Don't worry, it ain't gonna be used on prod ;) Just learning purpose